# How can I send a set of photos from iPhoto using my gmail address?

Tags: mail.app, email, photos.app, photos

I can email photos from iPhoto as follows:

1. Click on an event to open the folder.
2. Select photos (with <kbd>shift</kbd> and <kbd>command</kbd>).
3. Choose *Email...* from the *Share* menu.

This will send an email from my *@me.com* address.

How do I send photos from another email address (such as gmail)?

Of course I understand that I can *Reveal in Finder...* each photo individually and attach it to an email message. I can also run ImageMagick mogrify on the images and then send the result. I am looking instead for a quick method that lets me just click to select the photos and also gives me the option of sending down-sampled versions of the photos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this, you should get a dropdown selection box that has your various email addresses in it.  You can choose in there.  If your gmail doesn't show up there, then go to iPhoto in the menu, click Preferences, click Accounts, click the plus, click Email, click Add, click Gmail, and provide the relevant info.

Comment: Thanks.. I see it, but I'm having trouble with "The email server didn’t recognize your username/password combination." The culprit may be gmail's double-check (via a phone SMS). Checking...

Comment: Maybe.  I was able to add mine but I did it before I added 2 factor authentication to my gmail account.  It just kept working after that.  It's possible you may need to generate an app password for it within your google account and then use that password instead of the one you usually type in.

Comment: That was it. I needed to generate an iPhoto-specific password at https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords